# Matlab: plotting 3D Histogram

Tags: r, histogram, matlab-figure

I have a CSV file which has the following structure:

```
userID, movieID, rating

12,1,3 
13,1,3 
16,1,5 
18,1,5 
20,1,5 
22,1,5 
29,1,5 
54,1,3 
55,1,4 
57,1,4 
58,1,5 
63,1,5 
72,1,4 
73,1,5 
75,1,4 
78,1,3 
79,1,5 
82,1,4 
84,1,5 
96,1,4 
97,1,5
```

This is my humble code:

```
TrainingData = load('ratings.csv'); 
Z = TrainingData(1:5,:);
figure
bar3(Z)
title('Detached Style')
```

I want to plot for at least 10 rows consisting of the users, movies, and ratings.

The plot would look something like this:

[image: histogram_firstry]

I want, as an example, the users on the y-axis, the movies on the x-axis and the ratings on the z-axis.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You can do so using hist3D() function in r.

Comment: Thank you! But the thing is that Matlab's 3D plots are fantastic!

Comment: @AnubhavSingh I will try though! Do you have an example that you can share?

Comment: check this out: http://www.countbio.com/web_pages/left_object/R_for_biology/R_fundamentals/3D_histograms_R.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
library(plot3D)
data <- read.csv('data.csv')

x = c(seq(1, dim(data)[1], by=1))
y = c(seq(1, dim(data)[2], by=1))

zval = c(paste(unlist(t(data)), collapse=","))
zval = as.integer(as.list(strsplit(zval, ","))[[1]])
z = matrix(zval, nrow= dim(data)[1], ncol= dim(data)[2], byrow=TRUE)

hist3D(x,y,z, zlim=c(1,100), theta=120, phi=40, axes=TRUE,label=TRUE, nticks=5, ticktype="detailed", space=0.4, lighting=TRUE, light="diffuse", shade=0.5)
```

In the above code, x-axis represents the rows, y-axis represents columns in the data and z-axis represents the corresponding values.
The leftmost column is the first column in your data, followed by middle one and then the rightmost one.

Output Image:
[image]

There is always a scope of improvement but this will certainly give you an idea of how to do this.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am testing your code but the output is a white cube with nothing inside

Comment: I wrote and tested this code on my laptop and it's working fine. Are you sure you installed "plot3D " library? If not, you can do it using install.packages("plot3D").

Comment: Now it is working fantastically well!!! The thing was that I was loading a huge dataset. Like 180000 rows.

Comment: In such case, how do I have to modify the code so that I can use 200 rows?

Comment: You don't have to do anything as no.of rows and columns are not hard-coded. But, please check the range of values in the userID columns and enter into 'zlim=' of hist3D() function accordingly.